# Keytool change key password using 'keypasswd' throws 'Alias has no key' error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keytool

I am trying to change the password of the private key in my keystore. Doing the following:

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias <alias name> -keystore <keystore path>
```

I get:

```
Enter keystore password: <keystore password>
```

Which returns:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <ltsabreskey> has no key
```

This keystore was generated using a certificate that was extracted from a different keystore for which the password was lost. I'm trying to push an update to an existing app in the Play Store, can this be done with a newly generated keystore from the extracted certificate?

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE**: This answer applies to `JKS` and `JCEKS` keystore types and NOT `PKCS12`.

A keystore can hold a `secret-key`, `key-pair` (private key + certificate chain) or a `certificate`. You can identify these types by the these names respectively when you `-list` keystore -- `SecretKeyEntry`, `PrivateKeyEntry` and `trustedCertEntry`.

Of these the SecretKeyEntry and PrivateKeyEntry can be protected with their own password (could be different from the keystore password), if the keystore type is `JKS` or `JCEKS`. You **cannot** have different keystore and key password for `PKCS12` keystore type, the key password has to be the same as the keystore password.

Now, you mentioned in your last statement that the keystore you were working on was created with a certificate that was exported from a different keystore. There are two different use-cases to adding a certificate to a keystore. When you want to trust a particular certificate, you can add just the certificate itself, this is called the `truststedCertEntry`. Or you can add/update the certificate for a key-pair. Which means the certificate being added will be associated with a private key, this is a `PrivateKeyEntry`.

The alias you are working with is a `trustedCertEntry`, which cannot have a `keypass`. So when you supply the `keypasswd` command against this alias, it will through you the 'no key' error, which is what you are seeing.

---

To answer your specific problem, you cannot do the action you are doing without the private key, you extracted the certificate from the original keystore, but it doesn't have the private key, and you cannot extract the private key without the password. So, in short, you need to recover your old keystore, if you are unable to, follow the play store guidelines on what to do if the original keystore is not recoverable.

Comment: This does a good job explaining why the error happens, but provides no answer as to what can be done about it.

Comment: There is no fix for this. OP was working with the wrong data and expecting it to work differently, which is incorrect. I had explained and pointed out the problem in the last two paragraphs.

Comment: Of course there is no fix as-is, but an answer should at least point people in the right direction - e.g. obtaining the private part of the key as well. This guidance part is totally missing, therefore this is not an answer but an explanation.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Upvoted now :)

Answer (score 0):

did you check if the key is really in the keystore? Try this:

```
keytool -list -keystore <keystore path>
```

If the alias is not correct (key does not exist in keystore) i get the same error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and the key in question is present in the keytool -list output.